# how to avoid logging multiple number of times while using python threads

Tags: python, multithreading, logging

In a single thread.run() i am finding  a couple of strings in their corresponding webpages 
if found, I am logging a text to a log file.

lets say 4 strings in their corresponding 4 webpages.

when i run the a single thread, the log file shows 4 logs for each string in corresponding webpage

altogether i am getting 16 logs in a single thread, whereas i am expecting only 4 logs for 4 string searches.
i am not sure where its going wrong ..

https://github.com/sumankumar/websitemonitor

Any pointers to this design, or where i am doing mistake 
(I use global logger to all my files and just import the logger when necessary )

```
myLogFile = logging.FileHandler("./example.log")
```

i guess the fault is with logger object which i have created since

```
myLogFile = logging.FileHandler("./example.log",'w')
```

behaves a bit differently

(finally .. please point any other suggestions on my code :-) )

Comment: You are not showing any loggers here, but handlers. In other systems these might be the same thing, but in Python logging loggers and handlers have different roles. As well as reading the Python documentation, you can look at this tutorial for more information: http://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2009/09/python-logging-101.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use a [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html), and have all threads write data to the queue instance.  Then read from that queue from another thread and log there.  The queue takes care of locking/synchronization. (multi-producer/single-consumer model)